# How to get my FaceBook Public Profile URL via the Javascript API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the JavaScript API to log on to FaceBook, and I can call

```
FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,picture,website', function(data) {...});
```

to get basic details from my profile.  What I really want is a URL for my FaceBook profile that I can share with others - they would only be able to see public information from my profile - e.g. the sort of public profile page you get when searching for new friends, https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100002010472154&hc_location=friend_browser&fref=pymk for example.  I was hoping the **website** property would do this but no data is returned in relation to this and it's unclear whether this has been deprecated.

Is this possible?

So to clarify I just want my public profile page URL, I don't need access to feeds etc. I'm aware there are some other questions and answers in this space and that Graph API security has been tightened recently, but I don't think any other questions deal with access just to a user's public profile page URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "link" field would be what you need, i guess:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'id,name,email,picture,link'}, function(data) {...});
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that!

Comment: the link I get from this takes me to homepage instead of the person's profile.

Comment: this is something I get back, `https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/<some-id>/`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985497/https-www-facebook-com-app-scoped-user-id-app-scoped-id-redirects-to-facebo

Comment: or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958029/getting-facebook-page-with-app-scoped-user-id-is-not-possible-anymore/49958251#49958251

Answer (score 1):

The `link` field will give you a URL that automatically redirects to the user’s profile.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that!