# Getting facebook page with app_scoped_user_id is not possible anymore?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Below url gaves the user's facebook page till yesterday. But it's not working anymore.

https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/

Is there any way to get user's facebook page or it's disabled for a security reason?

Comment: I was going to ask this question 3 weeks ago...and seems like they disabled it.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, Facebook have chosen to disable the ability to resolve app scoped user IDs, so this feature is now gone. Seems they havent yet responded to people registrered to the bug to let them know.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/19/facebook-login-changes-address-abuse/

Comment: _“so this feature is now gone”_ - they are first and foremost saying there, that this is a temporary measure, until they figure out a proper way to handle this.

Comment: Yes it sounds like they intend to replace it with possibly something else at some point, but until they announce what that is, its safe to say that the mechanism as we knew it is not available any more.

Comment: @Cbroe It's now a permanent decision. You must request the user_link permission (app review required), and basically the profile link is now useless because of the restrictions imposed on getting this permission and the expiration of the link (90 days).

Answer (score 9):

There's a new permission in Graph API 3.0 that provides a URL link for a facebook profile:

```
user_link
```

In order to use that, you have to submit your facebook app for review (and likely have a legitimate reason you need this information.

Update: I went through this process, our app got approved for user_link permission, and it works as advertised.

The user_link variable is an app scoped link that will work as long as the app remains approved, and will stop working if the app should get removed or they revoke the approval. So it's a special URL that really only works as long as the FB app is around.

Comment: my app is reviewsed and approved but when i request user_link the graph api return failed result. Why could this be?

Comment: Any one got a solution for this issue? I am stuck as user profile link at this moment

Comment: ^^ you need to submit your app to facebook for approval for user_link. It's a pretty elaborate process, you have to provide an app store download, app ID, and a video of how the app will use the user_link setting.

Comment: And even when it is approved, the app-scoped ID you get back from the Graph API only lets you connect to the user if you're a friend! Pretty useless for most purposes.

Answer (score 3):

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2054375031451090/

Subscribe to that bug to get updated on the status.

There is also a blog entry about this: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/19/facebook-login-changes-address-abuse/ - so this is actually not even a bug.

Comment: And now, after nearly two YEARS, this problem still hasn't been addressed!

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer possible and will not be, according to https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/05/01/facebook-login-updates-further-protect-privacy/

Your best bet going forward is to open the Facebook site and search for the user name like so:

JavaScript:

Assume `user` is an object with a property called `name` that contains the user's name.

```
window.open("https://www.facebook.com/search/str/".concat(encodeURIComponent(user.name)).concat("/keywords_users"));
```

In most cases this will allow you to quickly find the person in question, given that you can still display their profile picture using the app-scoped ID on whichever site lists users. It's not great, but it may be of help to someone. We've resorted to this solution in our CRM.