# How I can get users public profile url using Facebook social login (graph API v.2.11) app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook graph API v.2.11 and social login. My client wants to stores those users who is using facebook social login And for that we need those user public profile url. Under which field we can get this? are Need some addition settings to get it?

Comment: In API v2 there is the `link` field (containing the app-scoped user id, when navigated to in a browser this would redirect to the real profile URL), but that has been removed in v3. There is no way to get the real profile URL via API. _“My client wants to stores those users who is using facebook social login And for that we need those user public profile url.”_ - why, what does storing user data have to do with the profile URL to begin with?

Comment: Hi CBroe, Since v3 has introduced from May 1, can app admin can review the users who are using social login of this app?

Comment: What do you mean by “review”?

Comment: Review Mean just want to check who is using this app manually by going to the user profile.

Comment: What for? What info is the client looking for?

Comment: The public profile url just.

Comment: That doesn’t answer the question what they are hoping to gain by “looking” at that.

Comment: Actually I do not know, I was just asked to get the user public profile url when they are using facebook social login. And I got the url something like https://www.facebook.com/10056709081xxxx/ when I try to visit the url I redirect to https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10056709081xxxx/.

Comment: Since it is app_scoped_user_id can admin some how use this url to validate the user? I mean can app admin go to user facebook profile?
Do we need some extra service from fb graph api to do so?

Comment: Well to better protect user’s privacy, Facebook does not want apps to be able to link to the profile any more. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49958029/1427878 (Plus, as I said, they already removed the corresponding field in v3.0)

Comment: Thank you very much CBroe, I got my answer.

Comment: They introduced a new permission `user_link` in v3.0 that can be used to explicitly ask the user to allow access to their profile URL, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.0#login

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the user for `user_link` permission to be able to do that and then use `/me?fields=link` endpoint to get the profile link. You can find more details here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_link