# https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/ {app_scoped_id} redirects to facebook homepage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using graph api **v2.5** to obtain app-scoped user id.

Recently, I have been unable to access user profiles using https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/ `{app_scoped_id}` as it currently **redirects to facebook's homepage**.

I have also tried using **v2.10** and added the **link** field which **returns**  https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/ `{app_scoped_id}` which **redirects to the homepage.**

Any suggestions?

Comment: No actually all I found was the answer to "how to get the profile from app scoped id " which is to use the URL that redirects me to the homepage but if you found a question with the answer to why this URL redirects me to the homepage instead of the user's profile, please do comment it here because I didn't find any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like they disabled this feature last week: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/19/facebook-login-changes-address-abuse/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I hope they create an alternative way soon